# How to get the selected item of Android Spinner?

Tags: android, android-spinner

How to get a selected item from a spinner in android?

Answer (score 1):

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
            // your code here
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
            // your code here
        }

    });
```

**Note:**

The documentation for the [Spinner widget](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html#setOnItemClickListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener%29)  clearly states:

```
A spinner does not support item click events. Calling this 
method will raise an exception.
```

Better use  [OnItemSelectedListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html)  instead, as above.

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity:

```
mSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.my_spinner);

// Define your adapter, in my case I have a class (SpinnerData) so I get an ID instead of the spinner's text 
ArrayAdapter<SpinnerData> myadapter = new ArrayAdapter<SpinnerData>(
  this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new SpinnerData [] {
  new SpinnerData("1","Item 1"),
  new SpinnerData("2","Item 2")
});

myadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    mSpinner.setAdapter(myadapter);
    mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

This is useful if you have other elements in the form that trigger the onItemSelected event:

```
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id{
    SpinnerData sd;


    switch (parent.getId()) {

    case R.id.my_spinner:
        sd = (SpinnerData)mSpinner.getSelectedItem();
        // do something with sd.id
        break;
```

...
}

As reference, the SpinnerData class:

```
public class SpinnerData {

public String id;
public String name;

public SpinnerData(String _id, String _name) {

    this.id = _id;
    this.name = _name;

}

public String toString() {
    return this.name;
}

}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code..

```
sp2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
 {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int selected_item_position = arg2;
        String selected_item=sp2.getSelectedItem().toString();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
 });
```